# What is the practical use of Assur Groups and structural analysis?

Tags: mechanisms, robotics

In Mechanisms and Machines Theory we were introduced to Assur groups and structural analysis where a mechanism is subdivised into elementary Assur groups of different classes. 
But what is really the practical use of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things have to be assembled. Assur group gives you a catalog of possible ways to make a rigid assembly out of joints. Each joint in this case represents a connection that will be assembled later, or locked down in case of foldable structures meant for reuse.

Being 0 degrees of freedom means that analysis of these is straight forward. Recognizing them will also make kinematic and dynamic analysis easier since you can replace them with a single rigid body.

Since assur groups can be predicted in a organized manner nothing stops you from generating a very big catalogue of these. Allowing you to systematically search for new solutions for the task at hand.

Comment: As far as I know, they can only be applied on planar mechanisms, is there a similar approach for spatial mechanisms?

Comment: @Abdeljalil Well yes, but there are some cases that dont reflect the theory. So its only 90% accurate, if you refrain from using spherical joints its almost completely accurate. Anyway nearly everything you see around you is designed with planar mechanism in mind

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, can you recommend resources or books for further reading? The subject is barely mentioned on the web.